Book on market microstructure and widely used execution strategies
More or less the same question as Book on market microstructure. Just want to see if any important update is out there after 10 yrs.
One additional aspect I would like the book(s) to touch is the widely used execution strategies, eg TWAP, VWAP, and give some insight on those that are in-house built by the big banks.

This question is similar to: What are the quantitative finance books that we should all have in our shelves?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@DimitriVulis The suggested link and answer there are on very general quant finance topics, which do not include execution and market microstructure specifically.
